# How to select students who got above average?

Tags: sql

How to list all students who got above average grade of their group in SQL table? We have 6 group_ids so there six different average grades.

```
group_id student grade
1         James   85
1         Adam    96
2         Tom     56
2         Jane    89
2         Anny    90
```

Result:

```
group_id student grade
1         Adam    96
2         Jane    89
2         Anny    90
```

Comment: This will helps you on future questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What RDBMS?  Are windowing functions allowed?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Locality = 'Lake Woebegone';`

Answer (score 2):

ashkufaraz's answer is closer but not quite right

```
select group_id,student,grade from students one where grade >
(select avg(grade) from students two where two.group_id = one.group_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is just tagged SQL, so this is an answer using standard SQL:

One option is to use a window function:

```
select group_id,student,grade
from (
  select group_id,student,grade, 
         avg(grade) over (partition by group_id) as group_avg
  from studends
) t
where grade > group_avg;
```

This has the additional benefit that you can also display the group average along with the result with no additional join or sub-select.